# 2D and 3D Surface Composition from 2 different applications on andorid 2.2

Tags: android, opengl-es, 3d, gpu

I am interested in knowing & understanding how does the 2D drawing & 3D surfaces are composited on android froyo 2.2 or in any flavor in general from 2 different Applications, For ex how are the surfaces of Live Wall paper & Launcher surface get composited & displayed .The 2D in the sense that launcher application seems to cratea surface & draw on the canvas & latter passes the drawn canvas buffers to surface flinger which in turn writes them as textures using openGLES glTeximage to the GPU & Live Wall paper seems to use the libRS render script for making the openGLES calls .

The question is how do the 2 surfaces get composited, Does surface flinger composes them as 2 separate layers, any description how an openGLES driver would do it will also be helpful .

---

Thanks alot but I will say that again the activity is single & in this case both the top & bottom surfaces will be submitted to the surface flinger & they will be composited using the openglES calls in surface flinger .

```
GLenum src = mPremultipliedAlpha ? GL_ONE : GL_SRC_ALPHA;
glEnable(GL_BLEND);
glBlendFunc(src, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
glColor4x(0x10000, 0x10000, 0x10000, 0x10000);
```

I am trying to understand the case when there are 2 different activities one activity is using renderscript/GL10(which I will say is 3D ) & the other activity is drawing using surface view on a canvas(which I will say is 2D or UI)

Answer (score 0):

You can create two or more surface view and assign it to one activity using `addContentView()` and `setContentView`. Let's say you will need two surface, surface_buttom and surface_top. You can do :

```
setContentView(surface_buttom);
addContentView(surface_top);
```

on your activity. Make sure you create the top surface background as transparent. Or else, the buttom layer cannot been seen.